# Wordpress cached image issue

Tags: wordpress, image, caching

I am having an issue with image caching I believe. Not 100% sure thats the issue, but perhaps someone with greater expertise could assist.

In my wordpress site, I have some images that were uploaded via the media library. Now, when I first enter the site that has no cached info from the site, the images load and display properly. But, when the site has been cached, the images are loaded, but are not displaying on every reload.

The reason I know is, because when I do a hard refresh (Shift + F5), where I am reloading the site from square one, I get the images to display properly again.

Any reason why this might be happening? I am completely lost, and don't know where I could start to fix this problem.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: can u share the link.

Comment: Oh my. I am extremely sorry, I was supposed to add that. Got busy with work. Here is the link.

http://www.dev.andylanclos.com

Comment: Still searching for a resolution. If anyone could suggest something, would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: link aint working.

Comment: [link](http://dev.andylanclos.com) Try this